# Colocar imagen en etiqueta de Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Estoy trabajando con la biblioteca `Chart.js`

```
<canvas id="popBackend" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Y el respectivo codigo js por su puesto

```
var popCanvas = document.getElementById("popBackend");
var barChart = new Chart(popCanvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Laravel", "Java", "MySQL", "PHP", "MariaDB"],
        datasets: [{
            axis: 'y',
            label: 'Experiencia',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
                'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {

                    font: {
                        size: 14,
                        family: 'Arial',
                        style: 'normal',
                        weight: 'bold',
                    },
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    font: {
                        size: 14,
                        family: 'Arial',
                        style: 'normal',
                        weight: 'bold',
                    },
                    color: 'white'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

En el apartado de `options` he logrado configurar algunos estilos y colores de las etiquetas de la gráfica, y ha quedado de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo me gustaría colocar el respectivo icono de cada tecnología, después de su nombre para darle un poco mas de estilo a la gráfica, hay alguna manera de lograrlo, gracias de antemano

Comment: Acá encuentras una solución a un caso parecido https://stackoverflow.com/a/62862487/15298643